# Firebase Data is not loaded into tableview data model

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview, firebase, swift3

The problem in the given code is, that the Firebase Data is not loaded into the Arrays before they get returned. Since I am new to swift I am really satisfied with my data model set up to load multiple sections into the tableview and don't want to change everything. The only problem is as I said, that the Firebase data collectors need some kind of a completion handler, but I don't really know how to apply them and I have no idea how to change the following code as well...

This is the class which defines an object:

```
class Court {

var AnzahlToreKoerbe: String?
var Breitengrad: String?
var Groesse: String?
var Hochgeladen: String?
var Laengengrad: String?
var Stadt: String?
var Stadtteil: String?
var Strasse: String?
var Untergrund: String?
var Upload_Zeitpunkt: Int?
var Platzart: String?

init(AnzahlToreKoerbeString: String, BreitengradString: String, GroesseString: String, HochgeladenString: String, LaengengradString: String, StadtString: String, StadtteilString: String, StrasseString: String, UntergrundString: String, UploadTime: Int, PlatzartString: String) {
    AnzahlToreKoerbe = AnzahlToreKoerbeString
    Breitengrad = BreitengradString
    Groesse = GroesseString
    Hochgeladen = HochgeladenString
    Laengengrad = LaengengradString
    Stadt = StadtString
    Stadtteil = StadtteilString
    Strasse = StrasseString
    Untergrund = UntergrundString
    Upload_Zeitpunkt = UploadTime
    Platzart = PlatzartString

}
```

}

This is the class which collects the objects and load them into multiple arrays, which are then called with the getCOurts function in the tableViewController:

```
  class Platzart
{

var Courts: [Court]
var name: String

init(name: String, Courttypes: [Court]) {


    Courts = Courttypes
    self.name = name

}

class func getCourts() -> [Platzart]
{

    return [self.AllSoccer(), self.AllBasketball(), self.Test(), self.Test2()]

}
```

This is an example private class function which loads the data:

```
   private class func AllSoccer() -> Platzart {

    var allSoccer = [Court]()

    let databaseref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    databaseref.child("Court").child("Fußball").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in



        if let Courtdictionary = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] {

            let city = Courtdictionary["Stadt"] as? String
            let district = Courtdictionary["Stadtteil"] as? String
            let street = Courtdictionary["Strasse"] as? String
            let surface = Courtdictionary["Untergrund"] as? String
            let latitude = Courtdictionary["Breitengrad"] as? String
            let longitude = Courtdictionary["Laengengrad"] as? String
            let size = Courtdictionary["Groesse"] as? String
            let Userupload = Courtdictionary["Hochgeladen"] as? String
            let timestamp = Courtdictionary["Upload_Zeitpunkt"] as? Int
            let numberofHoops = Courtdictionary["AnzahlToreKoerbe"] as? String
            let courttype = Courtdictionary["Platzart"] as? String

            allSoccer.append(Court(AnzahlToreKoerbeString: numberofHoops!, BreitengradString: latitude!, GroesseString: size!, HochgeladenString: Userupload!, LaengengradString: longitude!, StadtString: city!, StadtteilString: district!, StrasseString: street!, UntergrundString: surface!, UploadTime: timestamp!, PlatzartString: courttype!))
            print(allSoccer)


        }
    })

    return Platzart(name: "Fußballplatz", Courttypes: allSoccer)
}
```

The data is then loaded into the tableview:

```
class CourtlistViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

 lazy var Courtarrays: [Platzart] = {

    return Platzart.getCourts()

}()

@IBOutlet weak var CourtlisttableView: UITableView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    CourtlisttableView.delegate = self
    CourtlisttableView.dataSource = self
   }

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    CourtlisttableView.reloadData()
}

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

   let Courttype = Courtarrays[section]

    return Courttype.name

}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {


    return Courtarrays.count

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


    return Courtarrays[section].Courts.count

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cell = CourtlisttableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Court Cell", for: indexPath) as! CourtCell

    let Platzarray = Courtarrays[indexPath.section]
    let Sportplatz = Platzarray.Courts[indexPath.row]


    cell.updateUI(Sportplatz)

    return cell

    }

}
```

This procedure works well with data which I append to an array manually. For the Firebase Sections (AllSoccer() and AllBasketball()) only the headers are loaded and displayed.